# Dealing with comments only within a certain range in a For Each loop

Tags: excel, vba

While researching different aspects about comments and writing a few macros dealing with comments, I constantly saw and used ActiveSheet.Comments when performing any actions on comments. I haven't found any examples where we manipulate just a certain range. (Except a single cell but I couldn't get it to work with a larger range and wasn't grasping the on error statements.) I cannot do this by comment number because the sheet is edited by multiple people with many rows being backend formulas hidden in rows.
I've tried setting a range and within with statements but just can't get it.

(runtime 438 on 3rd line)

```
Set rngComments = Sheets("Rate Calculator v6").Range("F3:N46").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)
With rngComments
  For Each Cmt In Application.rngComments.Comments 'also tried removing ".comments", same error
  Cmt.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Next Cmt
End With
```

(runtime 13 type mismatch on last line if I try:)

```
Dim rngComments As Range
Dim Cmt As Comment
For Each Cmt In rngComments
```

I've also tried removing the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments) and a few other change ups but to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: `rngComments` is a `Range` object, not a `Comments` collection. Loop through each cell in the range and access its Comment property.

Comment: For Each cell In rngComments 
    With cell
   .Cmt.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End With
    Next cell
I still get error 438

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this (as per Rory's comment). Note that `cmt` is declared as a range not a comment.

```
Sub x()

Dim rngComments As Range, cmt As Range

Set rngComments = Sheets("Rate Calculator v6").Range("F3:N46").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeComments)

For Each cmt In rngComments
    cmt.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
Next cmt

End Sub
```

Comment: So close yet so far. Thank you so much. I don't think I would've come up with this solution. I wouldn't have expected the "cmt.comment.shape" line to have the "Cmt" range before ".comment" since it was expressed in the for each line. Thanks for the help.

Comment: My pleasure. As Rory says the comment is a property of the range object and so has to be referenced in each iteration of the loop (so you know which comment to which the code refers).